# circle image slider with Owl JS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I have a pretty basic layout

```
<section id="team" class="section">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="team-carousel owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <div class="item"> <img src="https://pcm.ipreo.com/App_Themes/ILevel/infographic09092015/images-desktop/circle-person-01.png"></div>
          <div class="item higher"> <img src="https://pcm.ipreo.com/App_Themes/ILevel/infographic09092015/images-desktop/circle-person-01.png"></div>
          <div class="item"> <img src="https://pcm.ipreo.com/App_Themes/ILevel/infographic09092015/images-desktop/circle-person-01.png"></div>
          <div class="item higher"> <img src="https://pcm.ipreo.com/App_Themes/ILevel/infographic09092015/images-desktop/circle-person-01.png"></div>
          <div class="item"> <img src="https://pcm.ipreo.com/App_Themes/ILevel/infographic09092015/images-desktop/circle-person-01.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I am trying to make a full width image slider that uses circles.  Alternative images should be placed slightly higher than other images.  I am trying to produce something like the following
[image]

I have decided to use [owl JS](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html)

I have managed to get some elements in place, but struggling with others.  Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/16/) I have produced.  First thing I am wondering is why does owl-item get given a width?  I ideally need to model owl-item around the image, maybe give it a little padding to make it look like 2 circles.

Second issue is that it does not seem to like me placing alternative images higher.  I have attempted to do this with a negative margin top but it does not appear to have done anything.

Any advice/help much appreciated. I gave each slide item a background color so I could see how the image looked within this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can check this full example base on OWL JS caraousel slider with team presentation.

```
$(function() {
  $('.owl-carousel.testimonial-carousel').owlCarousel({
    nav: true,
    navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'],
    dots: false,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
      },
      750: {
        items: 2,
      }
    }
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPXOVL